# Stuck with PHP Square API - AUTHENTICATION_ERROR

Tags: php, curl, square, square-connect

I want to use Square API for a project in order to push generated orders in an existing Square POI.

To do that I need to use the Checkout API with my personal app access token generated on the square dev portal but it keep telling me I do have insufficient permissions for this actions!

API Answer

[image: API Answer]

API CALL

[image: API CALL]

Square Doc

[image: Square Doc]

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Put a "!" bevor your links `![Text][1]` or `![Text](Url)` to show the image

Comment: I do not see the header Authorization and Content-Type being set in your request. Please set them

Comment: Can you share the headers section in Postman? Also note that Square has a pre-made Postman collection that might be easier for you. https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/getting-started-with-postman-and-squares-apis-e6bd0f2a8a75

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to embed images !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers !

Even with the official Postman it seems that the error occurs again :(

[Postman header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVctU.png)

I just added the location_id and token variable in Postman and the response is again a 403 error.
It's the same for my PHP script using the official Square connect library.

```
SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken('sq0atp-TOKEN');
$api_instance2 = new SquareConnect\Api\OrdersApi(); 
$body = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateOrderRequest();      
$itemstobuy = array(array("catalog_object_id" => "FYFGTSEZBVFP3BYECIJOCYAC", "quantity" => "1"), array("catalog_object_id" => "TMIQXB7RZY4EPXQZZAO3QVYM", "quantity" => "1"));  

$body->setIdempotencyKey(uniqid());
$body->setLineItems($itemstobuy);
$body->setReferenceId("Test".uniqid());   


try {          
   $api_instance = new SquareConnect\Api\CheckoutApi();     
   $checkout = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateCheckoutRequest();   
    $checkout->setOrder($body);     
   $checkout->setIdempotencyKey("Test_".uniqid()); 

    try {         
       $result = $api_instance->createCheckout($location_id, $checkout);         

     } catch (Exception $e) {            
        echo "The SquareConnect\Configuration object threw an exception while " .        "calling CheckoutApi->createCheckout: ", $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;   exit; }       

} catch (Exception $e) {    
      echo 'Exception when calling OrdersApi->createOrder: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
```

}